# Raspberry Cron don't work

Tags: cron, bash

Every 15 minutes, I need to run a PHP script. So I created a execute.sh file containing this line:

```
#!/bin/sh
php execute.php >> twitter.log
```

When I run the script manually, it works. Oddly, running it from `cron` is not working. Here is the contents of `crontab`:

```
*/15 * * * * /var/www/TwitterBot-master/execute.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Obviously, the script has the right permissions.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What crontable are you using? root or user?

Answer (score 3):

You should always use the full path when you don't know the execution environment.

Use the full path to the php executable.

Perhaps

`/usr/bin/php /var/www/TwitterBot-master/execute.php >> /var/www/TwitterBot-master/twitter.log`